# What kind of Error Detection Analysis does the Netbeans IDE have?

Tags: netbeans, error-detection

I'm doing some research on Netbeans IDE. I mean, why use ActionPMD and FindBugs plug-ins when Netbeans already has a built in error detection system? Is the difference really that significant?

Comment: If it needs to run the program to detect the errors, it's dynamic. If it detects the errors without running the program, it's static.

Comment: @user919789 Your comment looks fairly silly in the view of the **[timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9083850/timeline)**. Your edit made the comment _look_ obvious, but that was after the comment.

Answer (score 1):

FindBugs and ActionPMD "dig deeper". Without them, Netbeans can easily find issues like a local variable that is written to but never read. FindBugs will go a step further, and find streams that have not been closed ext..Some of the rules also include tests for "best practices" and possible security issues.

Just to clarify on the comment above: FindBugs and ActionPMB are both static analysis tools. In my experience, FindBugs is useful for finding subtle flaws and performance issue.